# Get List of tables as list to Table B in ASP.NET Core with FF Core 6

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, lambda, orm, entity-framework-6

Folks,

Need one help to get the list of table records with below structure using LINQ(EF .NET Core) and ASP.NET Core

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE TableC
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCAR(256),
    TableAId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA(Id),
    TableBId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableB(Id),
);
```

Custom model for to get the records

```
public partial class HomeModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; } // TableC id
    public int TableAId { get; set; } // Table A id
    public string TableAName { get; set; } // Table A id
    public List<TableB> TableBList { get; set; } // Table B list

    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }
    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
}
```

I need the data in the form of list of TableB to the list of TableA. 
using the below LINQ query, I can able to get the records of TableC Id(only key) but unable to get the further records.

```
var recordList = _context.TableC
    .Include(C => C.TableCId)
    .GroupBy(G => G.TableAId)
    .Select(homeModel => new HomeModel()
    {
        Id = homeModel.Key,
        TableAId = ",//homeModel.FirstOrDefault().TableA.TableAId,
        TableAName = ?, 
        TableBList = ?,    
    });
```

Thanks for your suggestions in advance!!

**Input**

*TableA*

```
ID  Name
1   A
2   B
```

*TableB*

```
ID  Name
1   A
2   B
```

*TableC*

```
ID  Name TableAId TableBId
1   A       1       1       
2   B       1       2
3   C       2       1
4   D       2       2
```

**Desired Output**

```
TableAId : 1, TableAName :"A"
    TableBId : 1, TableBName : "A",
    TableBId : 2, TableBName : "B"
TableAId : 2, TableAName :"B"
    TableBId : 1, TableBName : "A",
    TableBId : 2, TableBName : "B"
```

Comment: Possible please update with sample data and desired output.

Comment: @SelvaTS please let me know. Updated desired output

Comment: How your TableA, TableB and TableC referenced?

Comment: Through `TableC`

Comment: Not in database, How the TableA, TableB and TableC models referenced? Possible post your EF models for Table A, B and C.

Comment: Same way it is referenced. I created from DBFirst approach and actual model (TableA, TableB & TableC) is not modified